# How to program hotkeys to implement specific cell format in excel

Tags: excel, format, assign, hotkeys

I want to format a cell with a hotkey for a number.

For example, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> formats a cell with 3621 like this: "3,621.00"
I want to assign a hotkey (for example <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) to format a cell with 3621 to look like this "3,621" with no decimals.

Currently I have to do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> twice to get to a comma separated number with no decimals.

So far any search I have done basically just showed how to build a macro to perform this in VBA, which is not the solution I am looking for.

I just want to assign my own set of three hotkey to obtain desired format. I would even be good with reassigning <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to just drop the decimals if that's possible.

Comment: Currently you are using built in short cuts. You can easily record a macro following this procedure and manually assign a shortcut. In this case, no numbers are allowed. Also consider @user10798192 solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Put these into a public module code sheet (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>) and run asignCSWhotkey.

When you tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, the currently selected cell or cells will have a no decimal, comma thousands number format.

```
Sub asignCSWhotkey()

    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="zeroDecCommaThou", _
                             Description:="No decimals with comma thousands separator.", _
                             ShortcutKey:="W"

End Sub

Sub zeroDecCommaThou()

    Selection.NumberFormat = "#,###0"

End Sub
```

This assumes that no other sub procedure has been assigned the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> sequence. If one has already been assigned then that hotkey should be removed first.

Comment: I'm always struggling a bit with a programmatically short cut assignment. It works though. In this case it might also be a bit easier to go Developer -> Macros -> Options to assign a short cut.

Comment: Yes, I only included the hotkey assignment as a VBA procedure for demonstration purposes. IRL, you would probably end up at the Macros dialog looking for anything previously assigned ctrl+shift+W in any event.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. However, when I run asignCSWhotkey(), it gives me the "Method 'MacroOptions' of object '_Application' failed